# How to set line color in Geojson layer using xamarin forms

Tags: c#, google-maps, xamarin.forms, geojson

I am new in Xamarin forms I want to add a line color to my GeoJson Layer. How Can I do this.

Please help me...

Here is my Code

```
   protected override void OnMapReady(GoogleMap map)
    {
        base.OnMapReady(map);

        GoogleMap gmap = map;

        GeoJsonLayer layer = new GeoJsonLayer(gmap, Resource.Raw.jsonFile, Android.App.Application.Context);
        layer.AddLayerToMap();

        GeoJsonPolygonStyle kk = new GeoJsonPolygonStyle();
        kk.SetPolygonFillColor( Android.Graphics.Color.Red);
        GeoJsonFeature gg=new GeoJsonFeature(null,null,null,null);
        gg.PolygonStyle = kk;
        NativeMap.InfoWindowClick += OnInfoWindowClick;
        NativeMap.SetInfoWindowAdapter(this);
    }
```

Comment: check this link it will useful- https://github.com/amay077/Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps

Comment: @PratiusDubey I want to add a GeoJsonLayer not shape and the cordinates is comes from API.